# navigator.connection.type always 0

Tags: cordova

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
    alert(Connection.WIFI);
    alert(navigator.connection.type);
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

}
```

Comment: In which platform are you facing this issue ?

Comment: I get the same problem in Android. cordova version 2.2.0

Answer (score 6):

Did you call checkConnection after the `deviceReady` event?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}
```

In the checkConnection just use `navigator.network.connection.type` instead of `navigator.connection.type` because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1807

Answer (score 5):

this appears to be a bug in cordova 2.2.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1807